# java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match

Tags: java, security, tomcat7, keytool

1. I created a java keystore with name **cloudsslkeystore.jks**

   ```
    keytool -genkeypair -validity 730 -alias cloudsslkey -keystore cloudsslkeystore.jks -dname "cn=localhost" -keypass password -storepass password
   ```
2. I exported it as certificate with name **cloudcertificate.cer**

   ```
    keytool -export -rfc -keystore cloudsslkeystore.jks -alias cloudsslkey -file cloudcertificate.cer 
    Enter keystore password:password
    Certificate stored in file <cloudcertificate.cer>
   ```
3. I added the certificate cloudcertificate.cer to my local java security folder

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security>keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias cloudsslkey -file cloudcertificate.cer
   Enter keystore password:changeit
   Certificate was added to keystore
   ```

   Now I used the same java keystore **cloudsslkeystore.jks** in **tomcat server of a different machine** by modifying server.xml

   ```
   <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
                  maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
                  clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="c:\keytool\cloudsslkeystore.jks" keystorePass="password" />
   ```

When I try to hit a webservice thru a java client, I get this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Problem writing SAAJ model to stream: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
 path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:159)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.getAllRecommendations(Unknown Source)
        at client.WSClient.main(WSClient.java:73)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValida
torException: signature check failed
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:458)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:749)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:696)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:214)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:174)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:137)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathVal
idatorException: signature check failed
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:17
4)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1302)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1258)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:201)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.unBuffer(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:89)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:63)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.write(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:80)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.write(UTF8Writer.java:143)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeRaw(BufferingXmlWriter.java:285)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeCharacters(BufferingXmlWriter.java:603)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:456)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check fail
ed
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:350)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:260)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:159)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:351)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:191)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:279)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:345)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:451)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:160)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:139)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:133)
        ... 47 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Signature does not match` error is the symptom that the server identity is unknown to the client, ie the client truststore does not have the server certificate.

Create the server certificate and add it to a keystore:

`keytool -genkey -noprompt -alias "$alias" -dname "CN=$dname_cn, OU=$dname_ou, O=$dname_o, L=$dname_l, S=$dname_s, C=$dname_c" -keystore "$keystore" -storepass "$storepass" -keypass "$keypass"`

and export it for the client into a truststore:

`keytool -export -alias "$alias" -storepass "$storepass" -file "$alias".cer -keystore "$keystore"`

If you want 2-way SSL then you have to repeat this twice, inverting, they both must know each other.

Now the tricky part is to build an `SSLContext` correctly and configure your client and server with it.

In Grizzly I do:

```
SSLContextConfigurator sslContextConfigurator = new SSLContextConfigurator();

// set up security context
sslContextConfigurator.setKeyStoreFile(configuration.getKeystore()); // contains the server keypair
sslContextConfigurator.setKeyStorePass(configuration.getKeystorePassword());
sslContextConfigurator.setKeyStoreType(configuration.getKeystoreType());
sslContextConfigurator.setKeyPass(configuration.getKeystoreKeypass());
sslContextConfigurator.setTrustStoreFile(configuration.getTruststore()); // contains the list of trusted certificates
sslContextConfigurator.setTrustStorePass(configuration.getTruststorePassword());
sslContextConfigurator.setTrustStoreType(configuration.getTruststoreType());
if (!sslContextConfigurator.validateConfiguration(true))
    throw new Exception("Invalid SSL configuration");
```

For advanced debugging do not forget `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");`

Comment: The `Signature does not match` exception does not mean that at all, and the OP states he has already done the import step.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the problem:
The SignatureException does **not** indicate that the issuer is unknown to the client. In that case a CertPathBuilderException would be thrown.

The SignatureException was actually caused by not having the self-signed certificate imported as **trusted** certificate which must be done by the additional parameter `-trustcacerts`.

To answer the question why someone should want to trust a self signed certificate: The server is used for test purposes for automated client tests connecting to the server over HTTPS.

Comment: This didn't help!! I used the additional param but it didnt work.

Answer (score 3):

```
-keypass password
```

Get rid of this parameter. The mechanism that supports `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` doesn't support key passwords, only keystore passwords.

Comment: But you can't generate a keystore without a password, can you? At least, I get a prompt to enter a password, and when I hit return I get `Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters`

Comment: @tbmsu Read what I wrote. I am speaking of *key* passwords, not keystore passwords.